# Globally downloaded nodemon doesnt reloading automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemon

I have downloaded **nodemon** package globally via `npm install -g nodemon` command. But when i run the server using `nodemon app.js` then it will start the server without having any issue but whenever i try to change some code in `app.js` then the nodemon doesnt reload it automatically while i refresh the browsers page. I still have to close the server using *ctrl + c* and then again i have to use `nodemon app.js` command.

Comment: Saving doesn't reload/trigger it at all? If not a setting is messing with it, default it should listen to your entire project for changes (but not re-run till saved).

Comment: Page should be updated whenever you update/save the file and refresh browser. Can you elaborate on what do you mean by "doesn't reload"

Comment: It is just like i create a server using **node app.js** command ..... There if i change my code and then i have to stop the server and again and i have to create the server then if i refresh the browser page then i can see the newly made changes on the browser screen...